# Number of special partitions that are mutually disjoint as sets

Tags: combinatorics

Let $M$ be a set with $2\;|\;M$. What is the number of mutually disjoint partitions, each consisting of subsets with a cardinality of $2$.

$|M|-1$ should be a trivial upper bound.

**Note**: I asked the same question yesterday, although I accidently deleted it.

Comment: you can undelete your question I believe

Comment: @Gortaur: I could not figure it out.

Comment: I cannot check it on mine questions - I guess they're too old. I thought I could do it - so sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By a very special case (known for a century or two) of [Baranyai's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baranyai%27s_theorem), the edges of a complete graph on $M$ vertices may be decomposed into $M-1$ perfect matchings (when $M$ is even).  These matchings give you the desired partitions.  There's a picture in the wikipedia link that indicates the general construction of the edge decomposition.